# Cloudfront can't reach secured endpoints on Spring boot deployed on EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-security, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

I have deployed a Spring boot application on Elastic beanstalk and a React application on S3 as a static website. I use Cloudfront to handle the routing between these two applications, and everything works. I can get all the data that I have on Spring boot (connected to Postgres RDS) with Postman and I can send a login call to a secure endpoint (with Spring security). Also I can call all the secure endpoints with postman after adding the needed headers.

My problem is when I try to make a call via CloudFront to the secure endpoints on EBS Spring boot, and I get 403. All other endpoints are working perfectly (with no spring security in them). Only the endpoints which are secured are giving back 403.

I'm using a header called Authentication with Bearer (that i generate when calling login) to send the request to the backend.

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, I found the answer. (I was busy with this problem for about two days and I found the answer after 20 min from me putting the question on StackOverflow) :)

The answer is: adding a Whitelist Header. Which is the Authentication header. Because Cloudfront delete this header when sending the request, so I had to whitelist it).

How to add a whitelist header:

Go to you Distribution -> Behavior -> choose the EBS behavior -> Edit -> create a new Cache Policy -> choose Headers -> and then choose whitlist

I hoop I can help someone with this and prevent spending two days finding the answer like me :)